# need python script to use already open Xvfb server process

Tags: python, linux, xvfb, headless-browser, pyvirtualdisplay

I have a php script that runs many python scripts. The python scripts utilize a headless firefox browser using pyvirtualdisplay and xvfb. My issue is that each python script opens a new Xvfb process on my linux server. Thus I get multiple processes stacking up and eventual run out of /tmp/ space.
My issue is similar to this one:
[Xvfb multiple displays for parallel processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987246/xvfb-multiple-displays-for-parallel-processing)
I would like to have one Xvfb server process open at all times and have all the python scripts utilize it.
Here is the python code I am using:
`#set pyvirtual display

    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))

    display.start()`

Comment: I have resolved the issue by adding this line in my python code:    `os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':1'`     and removing the lines listed above.

Comment: I also added this line `import os`  something about posting a question on here helps me get to an answer myself!!

Comment: @GarrettCosco: It's called [Rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), aka [Asking the Bear](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-August/026357.html) :)

Comment: @GarettCosco you should write and accept your own answer as an actual answer instead of a comment. I know it might seem dumb but it would be helpful for people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by removing these lines from my python code:
`#set pyvirtual display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))

display.start()`
and adding the following lines:
`import os

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':1'`

This way the python script uses the already open Xvfb process setup on display 1 instead of starting a new Xvfb server process.